# What's the impact of having an @Id annotated composite entity in Spring Data JDBC?

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have a composite entity class as below in my Spring Data JDBC project which can be mapped to the table `item`.

While fields `id`, `code` and `itemName` are from table `item`, field `groupName` belongs to another table, `item_group`.

I get this entity object successfully loaded by using a custom query in my repository as follows:

```
"SELECT a.id, a.code, a.name AS item_name, b.name as group_name from item a LEFT JOIN item_group b ON a.group_id = b.id where a.id=:id")
```

Is there any impact in having an `@Id` annotated composite class like this?

```
public class Item 
{
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String code;
    private String itemName;
    private String groupName;
    
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }
    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }
    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }
    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }
```

Comment: I think this is very bad practice. It would be much better to have a ItemGroup entity.

Comment: Actually, my requirement is to use 'Item' entity to capture all details from 'item' table. Since 'item' table is having only group_id, I had to join 'item_group' table to get name of group. With the above query, I am thus only loading the group name in 'Item' entity.

Comment: magicmn, I made a correction in my question, regarding the distribution of fields in tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first sight this does look off.

You won't be able to load, let alone save it using the standard CRUD methods.

It also looks wrong, because it looks like you are merging two aggregates: `Item` and `Group`, which really should be separate aggregates with no Java reference between them. See [*Spring Data JDBC, References, and Aggregates*](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates)

But it does actually make sense if you consider it a view for specialised context.
If you only need it for reading from the database it is quite a valid approach. It's simple and efficient, since it loads all required data in one select.

Assuming that is the situation you are in I would recommend the following:

1. Create a view in the database for the join. The join will otherwise repeated over and over again in each query.
2. If you have such a view you can actually remove the `@Query` annotation and just use the standard `find...` methods.
3. Don't let your repository extend `CrudRepository` but just `Repository` and add manually only the methods you actually need. This avoids confusion and makes it obvious that this repository and therefore the entity must only be used for reading.
4. If you use the standard `find...` methods you must have a properly annotated id property. If you don't use the `find...` methods, the `@Id` annotation is superfluous.

Comment: Thank you very much Jens. Noted your suggestions.